# How we increase the width of the column by using bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have one textbox like firstname fot that field i have given validation what's the problem is that validation displayed in the textbox but i want to displayed beside the textbox using bootstrap . How it is possible can anybody suggest me?

```
<div class= "span5">
  <asp:requirefieldvalidator id="" ..................></asp:requirefeidvalidator>
 </div>
```

Comment: you can add custom style css for span5. be careful please don't change bootstrap definition write your page specific style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Please have look for the same](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Usually we will give a input type and then specify the RequiredFieldValidator.

```
Name: 
<asp:TextBox id="Text1" 
  Text="Enter a value" 
  runat="server"/>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"  
  ControlToValidate="Text1" CssClass="alert-error"
  Text="Required Field!" 
  runat="server"/>
```

This example work pretty fine.There you don't have any styling issue Let me know if you need more info on the same. Have good coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">{your textbox here}</div>
    <div class="span4">{your validator here}</div>
</div>
```